# neo4j cypher - trouble making relation

Tags: mysql, graph, neo4j, cypher, relation

I'm trying to convert MySQL database to neo4j, but I don't understand how to create relation (don't understand means that I'm getting "an error")

I've exported MySQL table data to csv file

```
target_type, target_desc, parent_type
"ADMET","Target is not applicable for an ADMET assay (e.g., physchem property)","UNDEFINED"
"CELL-LINE","Target is a specific cell-line","NON-MOLECULAR"
"CHIMERIC PROTEIN","Target is a fusion of two different proteins, either a synthetic construct or naturally occurring fusion protein","PROTEIN"
"LIPID","Target is a lipid","MOLECULAR"
"MACROMOLECULE","Target is a biological macromolecule (e.g., glycoproteins, hemozoin, hydroxyapatite)","MOLECULAR"
"METAL","Target is a metal e.g., iron","MOLECULAR"
"MOLECULAR","Target has been identified as a defined molecular entity (e.g., protein or nucleic acid)",NULL
"NO TARGET","Target is not applicable for a screening assay (e.g., negative control/counterscreen)","UNDEFINED"
"NON-MOLECULAR","Target has not been defined at a molecular level, only the non-molecular entity which is affected (e.g., organism, cell line etc)",NULL
"NUCLEIC-ACID","Target is DNA, RNA or PNA","MOLECULAR"
"OLIGOSACCHARIDE","Target is an oligosaccharide (e.g., heparin, starch)","MOLECULAR"
"ORGANISM","Target is a complete organism","NON-MOLECULAR"
"PHENOTYPE","Target is a biological phenotype or process","NON-MOLECULAR"
"PROTEIN","Target is a protein or group of proteins","MOLECULAR"
"PROTEIN COMPLEX","Target is a defined protein complex, consisting of multiple subunits","PROTEIN"
"PROTEIN COMPLEX GROUP","Target is a poorly defined protein complex, where subunit composition is unclear (e.g., GABA-A receptor)","PROTEIN"
"PROTEIN FAMILY","Target is a group of closely related proteins","PROTEIN"
"PROTEIN NUCLEIC-ACID COMPLEX","Target is a complex consisting of both protein and nucleic-acid components (e.g., ribosome)","MOLECULAR"
"PROTEIN-PROTEIN INTERACTION","Target is the disruption of a protein-protein interaction","PROTEIN"
"SELECTIVITY GROUP","Target is a pair of proteins for which the selectivity has been assessed","PROTEIN"
"SINGLE PROTEIN","Target is a single protein chain","PROTEIN"
"SMALL MOLECULE","Target is a small molecule such as an amino acid, sugar or metabolite)","MOLECULAR"
"SUBCELLULAR","Target is a subcellular fraction","NON-MOLECULAR"
"TISSUE","Target is a healthy or diseased tissue","NON-MOLECULAR"
"UNCHECKED","Target has not yet been assigned","UNDEFINED"
"UNDEFINED","No target has been defined",NULL
"UNKNOWN","Molecular identity of target is unknown (e.g., pharmacologically defined target)","UNDEFINED"
```

After that I've created nodes with code

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///target_type.csv' AS line
CREATE (targetType:TargetType {id: line.target_type })
SET targetType.description = line.target_desc
RETURN targetType
```

The problem is when I try to create relations between type nodes. The following code gives message "(no rows)":

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///target_type.csv' AS line
MATCH (targetType:TargetType {id: line.target_type})
MATCH (parentType:TargetType {id: line.parent_type})
CREATE (targetType)-[:CHILD_OF]->(parentType)
RETURN targetType, parentType;
```

I've tried to rewrite NULL values in csv file, to set different labels in nodes (name instead of ID), but none gave me result.

Can someone help me how to get graph with these data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITED]

You need to remove the spaces around the commas in the header row of your CSV file.

With those spaces, `LOAD CSV` was only capturing the first column of data (`target_type`).

Comment: How is that? I've created 27 TargetType nodes from cvs. 

Maybe I don't understand how does this work. I have second query with loading csv again. There I use MATCH for all loaded TargetType as targetType (where id is target_type from csv). Second MATCH also uses loaded TargetType nodes, just referring to them as parentType (matching ID of loaded targetType with line.parent_type). Since all parent_type values are loaded in TargetType node, I don't get what do you mean by "You did not CREATE (or, safer, MERGE) any nodes with an id of line.parent_type"?

Comment: OK, taking a closer look, it turns out there is a very different reason for your issue. See my edited answer.

Comment: It works! :) I apparently wasn't paying attention to blank spaces. Thank you.